# How could I display a crosshair cursor with x-y coordinates when hovering over a picturebox?

Tags: c++, winforms, opencv, user-interface, c++-cli

I want to make a crosshair pointer when hovering over a picturebox and store a co-ordinates when mouse left button is pressed over a picturebox.

My code looks like below:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        cv::VideoCapture cap;
        cap.open(0);

        if (!cap.isOpened()) {
            MessageBox::Show("Failed To Open WebCam");
            _getch();
            return;
        }

        ///query_maximum_resolution(cap, pictureBox1->Width, pictureBox1->Height);
        cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, pictureBox1->Width);
        cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, pictureBox1->Height);

        Pen^ myPen = gcnew Pen(Brushes::Red);

        while (1)
        {
            cap.read(frame);

            pictureBox1->Image = mat2bmp.Mat2Bimap(frame);
            Graphics^ g = Graphics::FromImage(pictureBox1->Image);
            Point pos = this->PointToClient(System::Windows::Forms::Cursor::Position);
            g->DrawLine(myPen, pos.X, 0, pos.X, pictureBox1->Height);
            g->DrawLine(myPen, 0, pos.Y, pictureBox1->Width, pos.Y);
            pictureBox1->Refresh();
            delete g;
        }
    }
```

But when I run the code it becomes slower and non responsive. Any idea to make it fast and efficient.
Any help would be helpful.

Comment: Have you read this https://www.opencv-srf.com/2011/11/mouse-events.html ?

Comment: Yes I've gone through that tutorial but I don't know how to use that callback function in user interface. If you do know how to do it please help me out.

Comment: if you use highgui you can try this   https://docs.opencv.org/2.4.13.6/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#setmousecallback

Comment: like in this https://jayrambhia.wordpress.com/2012/09/20/roi-bounding-box-selection-of-mat-images-in-opencv/

Comment: Hey @ralfhtp, I appreciate your help and the links you've provided helped me a lot. Again thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IO happens on the UI thread, which is the main application UI rendering thread. Button click is an event handler and will come on the UI thread. If you have a while loop running inside your UI thread, it will make the application hang. Work done on UI thread should be small or Asynchronous.

Edit 1: Just found out that you have marked winform as one of the tag. If you are using winforms, you have to add a MouseHover event handler to your UI controls. Whenever the mouse reaches in this area, this method will be called (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.mousehover?view=netframework-4.7.2). In this method just write the above code without the while loop. Something like this.

```
private: System::Void button1_MouseHover(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    cv::VideoCapture cap;
    cap.open(0);

    if (!cap.isOpened()) {
        MessageBox::Show("Failed To Open WebCam");
        _getch();
        return;
    }

    ///query_maximum_resolution(cap, pictureBox1->Width, pictureBox1->Height);
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, pictureBox1->Width);
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, pictureBox1->Height);

    Pen^ myPen = gcnew Pen(Brushes::Red);

    cap.read(frame);

    pictureBox1->Image = mat2bmp.Mat2Bimap(frame);
    Graphics^ g = Graphics::FromImage(pictureBox1->Image);
    Point pos = this->PointToClient(System::Windows::Forms::Cursor::Position);
    g->DrawLine(myPen, pos.X, 0, pos.X, pictureBox1->Height);
    g->DrawLine(myPen, 0, pos.Y, pictureBox1->Width, pos.Y);
    pictureBox1->Refresh();
    delete g;
}
```

Note: This event also comes in the UI thread. This will come everytime mouse oves in the region of interest. Hence you will not need the while loop. Adding a while loop here will again result in the same issue that you have asked in the question.

Comment: I understand that when while loop is running inside UI thread, it will make the application hang, then how to get video stream from webcam?

Comment: What is the UI Framework that you are using ? I think you need a different pointer event like Pointer over. It depends on the UI framework that you are using.

Comment: Hey @virusrocks, Above code is written in Microsoft visual studio 2017

Comment: That is the IDE that you are working with. I want to know the technology used for creating the UI like XAML or WPF. Anyway, try to find another event like mouse over where you will get the event every time mouse is over a particular part of your UI. there write the logic to do what you want to do. Make sure dont add the while loop, because with every mouse movement you will get the event back. For every mouse over if the mouse hit tests to the surface area of your requirement draw cross hair once.

Comment: Hi @virusrocks, I used windows form and thanks for your idea i will give it a shot.

Comment: Hey @virusrocks, yes it did and i got another suggestion from my friend and both of your ideas have really helped me a lot. So thank you so much and have a nice day.

Comment: Please mark this question as answered if everything worked fine.